# Stack Exchange keyboard bindings trumping mine

Tags: bug, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using the [Firemacs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firemacs/) extension in Firefox to give me Emacs keybindings.

This works in most cases, but not on Stack Exchange.  Your editor is defining its own bindings, and not checking for collisions.  For example, C-g should deactivate mark, but instead it's popping up some sort of image insertion dialog.

Even if it's not possible to check for collisions in JavaScript, could you please provide a mechanism for disabling your accelerators?  It's severely impacting the usability of the site.